# Vertx high availability routing

Tags: routes, vert.x, high-availability

I'm trying to understand how exactly vertx should be configured for high availability.

I know that vertx supports high availability an is able to restart or redirect workload to another verticle running on cluster.

But how can it be solved for routing? My app is basically a web application and has one HTTP endpoint with a public URL - implemented as a standard Vertx webserver+router. 
Here's my problem - how to protect against crash of this web server/router?
My understanding is that I cannot have multiple http servers serving the same routes, or can I?

Traditionally, I'd use load balancer and two or more redundant HTTP endpoints, but I'm not sure how to implement this in vertx.

Will using Kubernetes for production be able to handle load balancing of the HTTP endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

If your application consists in a single verticle serving HTTP requests, you don't need Vert.x HA but a reverse-proxy / load-balancer in front of all the JVMs where your verticle is deployed.

If you have Kubernetes in production already: simply create a service in front of your replicas (often by selecting a label that your pods declare).

Otherwise, do not install Kubernetes **just** for this, it's overkill. There are many great opensource and commercial proxies/balancers (eg haproxy or ngninx).

Comment: setup will be not that simple. We have a cluster of servers, and multiple verticles. 
I assume Vertx HA will take care of redistributing load/restarting verticles if one of the servers crashes.

But verticle serving as webserver+router is our single point of failure, I'm not sure how to load balance that.
As far as I understand, there cannot be multiple verticles (webservers) listening to the same URL and port, right?

So I cannot have two webserver verticles, and load balance between them. I'd need to have two separate installations of the whole system.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that each of them could listen on a different port, and public URL will be URL of load balancer that redirects the request to one of these verticles?

Is this the standard way to handle http endpoints failover in vertx?